# In Rollup How do I get --external to work on the command line directly pointing to the module to exclude? (no node resolve plugin)

Tags: javascript, rollupjs

The documents talk about using `external` in the context of the node resolve plugin, but I am not using that. I would like to exclude lit-html (which is native es6 modules) so that those imports remain in the bundle.

In my module I import them with import `{ html, render } from '../../node_modules/lit-html/lit-html.js'`; and it works great in the browser.

I have tried every permutation of path including relative path like `rollup --format=esm --file=dist/bundle.js -- src/main.js --external 'node_modules/lit-html/lit-html.js'` and just get `[!] Error: Could not resolve entry (--external)`.

It does not even say if the file is found, never mind what the problem is.

Comment: why not use node resolve plugin?

Comment: @Troopers because then I would have one way to access the lit-html code in the code itself, and one way in the command line. This is a redundancy, extra complication and an unwanted dependency. I don't understand why I can't just refer directly to the file, that makes me think it must be a user error as something so obvious must be included?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems your command is wrong, use `-i` to indicate the input file or try moving `-- src/main.js` to the end of the command without the dashes.

Regarding the external part, don't think it will work without using the exact id of the import but worth a try.

Using a config file:

```
module.exports = {
      input: 'src/main.js',
      external:[
        '../../node_modules/lit-html/lit-html.js'
      ],
      output: {
      format: 'esm',
      file: './dist/bundle.js',
      sourcemap: true
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for your input, I changed it to closely follow the example in the docs with `"build": "rollup src/main.js --file dist/bundle.js --format esm --external '../../node_modules/lit-html/lit-html.js'"` and it now says `Error: Cannot fetch external module /home/david/sites/mvc-normalize-object-literal/node_modules/lit-html/lit-html.js`. This location is correct, if I click it the file opens. If I change the text of the external module to a nonsense name it just ignores it and bundles the entire thing with lit-html! Seems we are getting closer... what happened to error detection?!

Comment: Try with the external option as you had it, from the docs seems its the way to go `--external 'node_modules/lit-html/lit-html.js'` since it matches files not patterns.

Comment: If I do that, or even just `'lit-html'` it looks like it works, but it just goes ahead and includes the external. If I add any random name it does the same thing, it is like there is no error checking for a non existent file.

Comment: Well declaring externals that dont match any module is not an error. I think the error on your first comment may be due to importing lit-element several times, but with different ids (paths), so one is considered external and the other isn't which may create an internal conflict in rollup leading to that error.

Comment: I only import lit-html once in the whole app in one module with `import { html, render } from '../../node_modules/lit-html/lit-html.js';`. I don't understand what you mean by "declaring externals that dont match any module is not an error"... I can use --external '/bode_modules/lit-html/lit-html.js << note the typo, and it gives no errors, there is no such directory as bode. If I change that to `--external 'nonsense'` it seems to run just fine too. Do you not think this should throw an error? I have NO idea how I can make the lit-html import stay as an external, am I missing something? THANKS!

Comment: Am i misunderstanding what an ID is? How do I find the ID of lit-html?

Comment: I think `-- external 'nonsense'` should not be an error since that allows to reuse externals among different projects from a base configuration. About what an id is, I would say is the string you use in the import statement and not what it is resolved to but i'm not 100% sure

Comment: I would try using a config file and setting external to a function and log its arguments in order to see which id is being assigned to your lit-element import, and then use it from the cli. Remember to return false in the funcion so every module is included and all ids are loged.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but this is getting very complex for my skill level. I am not a library developer, I ironically wanted something easier than Webpack. I will try rollup-plugin-node-resolve and play about with that later... What a giant waste of time... arrghhhh!!!!

Comment: Setting external to `'../../node_modules/lit-html/lit-html.js'` works fine from the config file (that is the id btw). May some problem with the CLI format

Comment: I found the problem! I tried your config and it didn't work, so for a final try I deleted `import { classMap } from '../../node_modules/lit-html/directives/class-map.js';` and removed it from my code, then it suddenly worked!!!! No idea why, but it's time to celebrate! Thanks for your help :)

Comment: That would probably be importing lit-html again with a different id :)

Comment: That is what I don't understand, I am importing a totally different file, not `lit-html` but `class-map.js`. Inside this file it does include `import { AttributePart, directive, PropertyPart } from '../lit-html.js'`, but I don't see how that is my problem? I thought Rollup would deal with that, but I guess not. I think I can do everything I need Rollup to do now, so hopefully I will never have to cross the API again :)